# Python sqlite: Preventing SQL injection in table names

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-injection

pretty basic question here. In python, using sqlite3, I'm able to prevent most sql injections with ? placeholders. However this option doesn't exist for table names.

In most scenarios it's pretty easy for me to just check if the table exists, however I also need tables to be created from placeholders that will be **user supplied**.

How would I go about doing this?

edit: Honestly the associated question really doesn't help in this situation... The issue here is that I want a user to supply their own table name. Regardless I decided to use a scheme that I described in my own answer here so I don't really care about this question anymore.

Comment: Also why I can't I write 'Hi, ' at the beginning of my question without stackoverflow removing it, is that being too friendly?

Comment: Not really since the names will ideally be user supplied and I'd rather not have to learn an entire orm like sqlalchemy just for this one thing

Comment: "since the names will ideally be user supplied"—this is virtually always an indication that your architecture is broken. Why are you asking the user for table names?

Comment: "Also why I can't I write 'Hi, ' at the beginning of my question without stackoverflow removing it"—because it's irrelevant and distracts from the question. [High-reputation users are encouraged to edit such things out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/354577), so it's better to prevent them from being added in the first place. "is that being too friendly?"—Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum, [it's a wiki](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/12/28/stack-overflow-is-a-wiki/) disguised as a Q&A site. We optimize for future users looking for answers, not chit-chat.

Comment: I'd say 4 characters isn't so distracting but I understand the point. 

So maybe there's a better architecture for this but I'm writing an application to take in user data and then perform certain operations on it. So I want users to be able to import any type of data with as many data columns as necessary. Is there a better way to do that than using tables?

Comment: That's impossible to say without a lot more detail. What do you mean by "certain operations"? What is "any type of data"? Lots of data is most naturally expressed in a form where the idea of a "column" doesn't make much sense. Maybe you're looking for [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: I meant letting the user import a table of data. And then I'll be analyzing the data or displaying it

Answer (score 0):

Well it might not be best practice but my solution will just be storing the tables and column names as Table1, Column1, etc. I can store the names separately.